# Set Module name, Controller name, and Action name in Zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I recently started programming with Zend Framework.I want to change *module name*, *controller name* and *action name* of a module in my framework through coding, while coding in the same framework.

Its name is **Application**(module & controller) and I want to change it to *Institute*. Is this possible through coding?

I searched through Google for help, but either i couldn't find it or understand it properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you saying you have a module called Application and you want to rename it to Institute?

Comment: Yes @PurpleHexagon. and I would appreciate an edit to my this post, or other posts, because I am banned from asking questions, due to bad questioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just a case of renaming things:

Update all namespaces from Application to Institute in all the classes in the module including the Module.php

Update the name of the controller and it's entry in config/module.config.php

Make sure you update the name of your view directory if you have one in the module, ie view/application/index etc to view/institute/index and make sure you update the entry in module.config.php to the same path

Update name of Application directory to Institute

Update the name in the array of modules in modules.config.php or if you are using an earlier version application.config.php from under the modules key.

That's all I can think of you would need to do

******** EDIT ********

So the basic idea would be as follows:

Add a console in a new module (I've used zend mvc console but you should probably use https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-console as mvc console is deprecated)

module.config.php

```
<?php
namespace Rename;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
  'console' => array(
      'router' => array(
          'routes' => array(
              'rename-module' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => 'module rename <moduleNameOld> <moduleNameNew>',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                            'action'     => 'rename'
                        )
                    )
              )
          )
      )
  ),
  'controllers' => [
      'factories' => [
          Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
      ],
  ],
];
```

IndexController.php

```
<?php
namespace Rename\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Console\Request as ConsoleRequest;
use Zend\Mvc\Console\Controller\AbstractConsoleController;

class IndexController extends AbstractConsoleController
{
    public function renameAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        // Make sure that we are running in a console and the user has not tricked our
        // application into running this action from a public web server.
        if (!$request instanceof ConsoleRequest) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('You can only use this action from a console!');
        }

        $moduleNameOld  = $request->getParam('moduleNameOld');
        $moduleNameNew  = $request->getParam('moduleNameNew');

        $module = file_get_contents(getcwd() . "/module/$moduleNameOld/src/Module.php", 'r+');
        $updatedModule = str_replace($moduleNameOld, $moduleNameNew, $module);
        file_put_contents(getcwd() . "/module/$moduleNameOld/src/Module.php", $updatedModule);

        rename("module/$moduleNameOld", "module/$moduleNameNew");
    }
}
```

This can be run like

```
php public/index.php module rename Application Institute
```

I've only done renaming the module here and renaming the namespace in the Module.php

to finish this off you would need to recursively find all .php files in the Application directory and loop over applying the string replace (which should be improved really). Then you could update the view and application level config too with similar logic and using the steps above.

The code I've written is pretty bad and probably insecure but might help you along the way

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i have been assigned the task to do it through coding. Is there any way to do, what you have told me, through coding?

Comment: Yeah, there will be a way ... I can look at writing one. Would a shell script be ok? Or does it need to be something else?

Comment: It need to coded inside the zend-framework application ( as i am asked), but i would be grateful if you could show me how to do it using shell.

Comment: So you need a Zend Console command which will rename a module?

Comment: i would be grateful for that, since i don't know how to rename a module in console, but i am interested in this thing to be done using coding inside framework.

Comment: I've written a little bit of it to start you a long your way. It's not massively hard to do the rest I just don't have time

Comment: Would you suggest an edit to my post. I am banned from questions due to bad questioning, Thanks